# XPath to CSS Selector

Tags: xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I have the following xpath statement in a selenium test:

```
//tbody/tr[td/span[text()='IPODate']]/td[4]/input
```

It gets what I want but my tests are painfully slow in IE6. Anyone know how I would do the same selector as CSS selectors? I think I understand how to do each of these with exception to the text()="IPODate" part.

As requested here is an example of the table I am trying to select from:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" id="tblResearchItems" class="coolTable SingleItem">
        <tbody>
```

.... many many rows

```
<td>
    <input type="button" value="A" onclick="sA('secm.Company', 'IPODate', 299)" class="RButton NarrowButton2 A Show_N"/>
</td>
<td class="TCN">
    <span class="CN">IPODate</span><f/>
</td>
<td>
    <g/> 
</td>
<td class="TCV VerticalAlign">
    <input type="text" value="" onfocus="stLT(); hideLB(true)" onblur="mustBeDate($(this));" class="UpUI_Y  date NDD hasDatepicker" id="dp1260909771780"/>
    <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."/> <div/>
</td>
</tr>
```

...many many more rows...

in this example only one row has the IPODate cell.

Comment: #tblResearchItems > tbody > tr[td > span[text() = 'IPODate']] >  td[4] > input

maybe?

Comment: can you please put the HTML around that element so we can see how we can change it to the CSS selector. You havent given enough information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the CSS locator is `css=span.CN` for the span that has the text IPODate in it.

Saucelabs have a good explanaton of how it works on their [blog](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2009/10/selenium-tip-of-the-week-start-improving-your-locators/)

**UPD:**
Unfortunately CSS won't parse the entire tree when move up and down till it finds what it is after. This is the main reason why XPath is so slow. CSS finds an item and then can move laterally through the DOM. The CSS below will find the input box that is after the `TD` that has `class=TCN` which holds your span with text in the table.

**CSS:** `table > tbody > tr > td.TCN + td + td > input`

Comment: That is the rub though. I am trying to get the input element in a table row that contains a span with the text "IPODate"..