# How to extract attribute values using css selectors?

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

I want to select the values of attributes of an element. e.g If I have an input element

```
<input type="text" name=myInput value="100">
```

I can locate it using `input[name='myInput']`, but how do I get the value of it using a css selector?

BTW, I am trying to do this in Selenium using css selectors

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some hint as to the technology you are using to "select" and "locate". XPath in XSLT? JavaScript using DOM? JavaScript with jQuery? There is so much to guess amongst.

Comment: Sorry, this is in Selenium. I am trying to use CSS Selectors (instead of XPath) to get the value of an input element.

Comment: Apparently another person asked a similar question, but again that person wasn't trying to extract the value of the input element he was after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909584/xpath-to-css-selector

Comment: In your response below you mentioned you're using Selenium. Please change the title of your question to "How to extract attribute values with Selenium" to get better responses.

Comment: What language are using Selenium in. Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in Perl using WWW::Selenium then it's simply:

```
my $val = $selenium->get_value("css=input[name='myInput']");
```

If using another language then the Selenium library should support a get_value function/method.

Comment: Aha! that is my problem. I wasn't using "css=". Thank you.

Comment: BTW, another addendum to that question - what if I have other attributes? Let us say if I have a checkbox and I want to get the id of that checkbox or its onclick attribute etc. Is there any generic way to get value of any attribute of an element?

Comment: If what you're after is not handled by the basic Selenium API then there's always `get_eval()` that allows you to write javascript code and return anything you want: innerHTML, javascript variable, element attributes etc.

Comment: Example: `my $txt = $selenium->get_eval('document.getElementById("foo").title');`

Answer (score 9):

You might want to explain what you're trying to do with the value.  For instance, I have the following CSS to display the text of the links in the '#content' element in my print style sheet:

```
#content a:link:after, #content  a:visited:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
    font-size: 90%;
}

#content a[href^="/"]:after {
    content: " (http://example.com" attr(href) ") ";
}
```

Comment: I have a table where in, each row has an input element with value. I have to read all those values and return as an array. Does that help?
Just to add to it, I am getting that by 

table[class='tbl']>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(1)>input

And now I need to find out the value attribute of that input element

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    String nameAttribute=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Your css selector")).getAttribute("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your favorite JavaScript library should have some way to do this:

jQuery

```
$("input[name=myname]").val()
```

Prototype's method for CSS seloctors is $$() iirc.

For this example you could also use the native document.getElementsByName() method aswell.

Comment: I should've added this before. I am trying to do this in Selenium & I am trying to extract value using CSS locators that selenium understands. So I guess, I have to look at what JS library Selenium uses for CSS evaluation.

Comment: Please add the tag Selenium to your question and re-phrase it by adding "in Selenium" somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Selenium WebDriver there are 2 ways to do this

driver.findElement(By.name("myInput")).getText()
driver.findElement(By.name("myInput")).getAttribute(value)